# ASP.NET Page inside Android APP not calling some JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, asp.net, xamarin

I have a Xamarin project with both iOS and Android.
These are the nuget packages's versions:

- Android

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.FirebasePushNotification">
      <Version>3.4.35</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Common">
      <Version>120.0.0.5</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Iid">
      <Version>121.1.0.5</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging">
      <Version>122.0.0.5</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2578" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.7.5" />
```

- iOS

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.FirebasePushNotification">
      <Version>3.4.35</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging">
      <Version>4.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core">
      <Version>8.10.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Installations">
      <Version>1.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceID">
      <Version>4.3.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2578" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.7.5" />
```

- The APP runs an ASP.NET webpage.
- One page contains a list of elements with an "a" tag that links to an existing URL. This is done with an "asp:Repeater":

```cs
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rep_menu">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <div onclick="load('<%#Eval("URL")%>', this);">
             <div class="cell enlaces-menu">
                 <div class="imagen_enlaces"><%#Eval("image")%></div>
             </div>
             <a href='<%#Eval("URL")%>'>
                 <div>
                     <%#Eval("Title")%>
                 </div>
             </a>
         </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

<%#Eval("URL")%> is the actual url that I want to open. Neither the "OnClick" and the "<a href" opens the URL.

- It doesn´t work on Android, and it works perfectly on iOS.

**Also:**

- Other page has a button that ultimately runs the function window.location.reload()

```js
<script>
    function AgregarReservaPAGEMETHOD(_fecha, _lugar) {
        PageMethods.postback_AgregarReserva(_fecha, _lugar, document.getElementById("datosSelf").innerText, () => {
            window.location.reload();
        }, () => { window.location.reload(); });
    }
</script>
```

- "AgregarReservaPAGEMETHOD" is a WebMethod that basically calls the server to add a new registry in a table and then sends an Email using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
- It also doesn't work on Android but so in iOS

It's like if in Android JavaScript functions are not loading properly.

Any suggestions? Thanks beforehand!!

I've changed the code many times, nothing seems to work. What really grinds my gears is that is iOS works like a charm, there there's no issues...

Comment: Have you tested this on another Android device? Also, what happens if you change your code to simply `alert(...)` something? Does it work then?

Comment: Yup, I've tested it in many Android devices. I'll try the alert and tell you how it went. Thanks!!

Comment: I've added the alert() and it's also not firing.

Comment: Is there any log about this problem?

Comment: There is, but it doesn't pull out any exception because the main task is being done correctly. What it's not working is that callback function, in this case "window.location.reload()" but it also doesn't work with an "alert('Hi!')"

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem or more code snippets so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Hi! I've added some code. Let me know if you need something more. Thanks!!

Comment: If it is convenient for you, could you please [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Maybe I could try to, but it will definitely take me a while, at least until the 1st of April I won't be able to do it

Comment: Waiting for your news. :)